# Removable MicroSD card detected but not mounted

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd

I have recently switched from the stock ROM (4.4.2) for my Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo+ to Cyanogen 11 (4.4.4 - I wiped data, system and cache partitions before doing this). I have a 64GB external sd card formatted to FAT32 which was working fine when using my stock ROM but Cyanogenmod will not mount it anywhere. It detects the presence of the removable sd card as I am offered to erase it in the storage section in the settings. However, there are no files under /external_sd or /storage/sdcard1.

Is there any way I can fix this and mount my external sd card?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by converting my external SD card from FAT32 to NTFS using MiniTool Partition Wizard.